# What's the exact format of letters/text messages inside novels?

Tags: creative-writing, novel, formatting

The following is from [The Fault in Our Stars](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=Qk8n0olOX5MC&printsec=frontcover&dq=the%20fault%20in%20our%20stars&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMIl9Ky3rfOyAIVghuUCh1tkg2j#v=onepage&q=the%20fault%20in%20our%20stars&f=false):

[image]

If I'm not mistaken, this is the formatting:

- The font should be half the size of the normal font.
- They should be indented with twice the indent space.
- They should have the paragraphs separated by spaces that are half a scene break.

Am I right? Is this the common way of formatting letters and text messages inside novels?

Comment: I would also be interested in knowing about the font. In many novels, I see different sans serif fonts used for text messages. In a straight-text novel for Kindle Publishing, for example, are there some set fonts that are recommended for use when writing text messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the publication. For example, in many novels I read half the size of the normal font would make it unreadable. Double indenting is common. Italics or a script font for a letter is common. I have seen a number of different formats. It also depends on whether the whole of a letter or only part of it is being quoted. Sometimes, if a letter or message is very old the font will be more ornate.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question quickly, yes, that is pretty much the standard for letters within a novel. Though, as Tave said, it depends on the publication.

There is no universal format, but there are several things to keep in mind. Any long quotation (as in a letter) can be considered a block quotation. These are typically indented, and have either a slightly smaller font, or a monospaced font as found on typewriters. It makes the letter easier to read, and to distinguish from the remainder of the text.

As for text messages, it makes sense to follow a format similar to a letter, though you could make a case for an in-line quotation due to their brevity.

Really, outside of journal publication, formatting is a highly subjective element to writing. Depending on the type of narrative, it might make more sense to try things another way. *House of Leaves* comes to mind, which was meant to be frantic, crazy, and frankly impossible.

If you're not trying to create anything Dada, you've hit the nail on the head.